# Node.js: Available/Creating Web Proxies

Tags: web-applications, node.js, proxy, web-scraping

I'm trying to create a web proxy alot like [Proxify](http://proxify.com/) without th options that allows users to surf third-party websites instead of an iframe for maximum usability (Circumventing Iframe issues.).

How would I be able to achieve this?

Also, I've googled around and found some Node.js Web Proxies that don't seem to work anymore as they are out of date.

Examples:

- [Node Web Proxy Example 1](http://www.pgrs.net/2010/02/01/web-proxy-in-node-js-for-high-availability/)
- [Node Web Proxy Example 2](http://www.catonmat.net/http-proxy-in-nodejs/)

Are their any recent Node.js web proxies available?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use [node-http-proxy](https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy)

Their documentation is solid and they have an [examples](https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy/tree/master/examples) folder.

A lot of people use this in production. Nodejitsu itself uses it in production.

Comment: Thank you for finding this, so if I were to direct the proxy to a site all I would have to do is localhost:9000/http://Domain.com ?

Comment: @Trevor that's too vague. Just npm install it and try it.

Comment: Sorry I meant, how would I be able to browse a third-part website using this module?

Comment: @Raynos I'm sorry, documentation ?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Hoxy](https://github.com/greim/hoxy). I haven't used it myself, but I am working on a similar problem (I want to circumvent the iframe same domain policy), so from the quick glimpse that I took of the project it seems to do what you want.